# How to reduce the size of long titles in TOC

Tags: reledmac, section-titles

It seems that `reledmac` is incompatible with `secsty`. My aim is to reduce the font size of `\chapter` `\section` and `\subsection` because the work I am editing uses long titles and they don't fit quite well in the toc. Code:

````
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\lineation{page}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\Large}
\subsectionfont{\normal}
\subsubsectionfont{\normal}
\paragraphfont{\normal}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Introdução}
\chapter{Apresentando uma obra com longos capítulos}
\section{De como o autor deste erudito livro se resolveu a viajar na sua terra, depois de ter viajado no seu quarto; e como resolveu imortalizar-se escrevendo estas suas viagens}

\part{Texto original}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
Que viaje à \edtext{roda}{\Afootnote{roda \textit{A} em redor \textit{BC}}} do seu quarto quem está à beira dos Alpes, de inverno, em Turim, que é quase tão
frio como S. Petersburgo 
\pend


\endnumbering

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Sorry. I cut the first line of my code: \documentclass{book}

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is: `sectsty` does nothing at all in the TOC.

Comment: "It seems that `reledmac` is incompatible with `sectsty`." I would question that claim, since reledmac, too, does nothing to a TOC generated by traditional sectioning commands. When I remove pkg `reledmac` and all its specific commands in the MWE, I get the exact same TOC as with reledmac.

Comment: Are you getting an error or warning mentioning `reledmac` from your MWE?

Comment: @greg I see... Which package should I use? tocloft? My purpose is to handle better long titles in sections (for which I thought secsty was suited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution using `tocloft`:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\small\bfseries}   % for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small}             % for sections, etc.
```

The default for both is `\normalsize`; `\chapter` is additionally set in boldface: `\bfseries`. `tocloft` gives you the ability to customize this style, too.

Personally, I would not go below size `\small`; if you still find the titles are too long, do follow Peter Wilson's [advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625163/) and use the optional argument of sectioning commands.

Several commenters have pointed out that there is **no known incompatibility** between `reledmac` and `sectsty`, and your question does not really involve `reledmac` either. I would suggest that you please **edit** the title of the question to reflect this fact ("how to reduce the font size in TOC" or so), and also edit the first sentence.
TeX.SX is a reference for many new LaTeX users, and potentially confusing claims don't come off search results easily.

(If you, in fact, got an error/warning explicitly mentioning `reledmac`, do let us know!)

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional argument to the sectioning commands, e.g.

```
\section[Short title for the ToC and header]{Long title for the document text}
```

Similarly for `\part`, `\chapter`, `\subsection` etc.

Comment: If there is no other option I will use it... Anyway I would like to know whether  the problem is due to the sensitivity of reledmac?

Comment: @Sintram I don't believe that it has anything to do with `reledmac` which I can't see  changing `\section` etc.